# How I can run Powershell 5.0 foreach in parallel?

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, powershell-5.0, parallel.foreach, powershell-7.0

I've been writting powershell 5.0 script. In that script I have a lot of .csv files on location "C:\User\Count\Export" and I have a list of key words. I need to go through all key words and go through all .csv files and check if key word exists in .csv file. For that purpose I've been using foreach in foreach and that takes a lot of time. Is there any way to run this script in parallel and how I can write parallel script using powershell 5.0? Also, if you have some idea to do this using Powershell 7.0, that would be great.

```
$dir ="C:\User\Count\Export"
$items = Get-ChildItem $dir\*.csv
$file = "C:\User\Count\Result.csv"

$searchWords = 'word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6'
$counter = 0;
foreach($i in $searchWords)
{   
   $counter++;
   Write-Host $counter
  "$($i)," | Add-Content -Path $file -NoNewLine
   $sum = 0

 Foreach ($item in $items)
{
    
    $count = (get-content $item | select-string -pattern "$i").length
    $sum = $sum + $count
            
    "$($count)," | Add-Content -Path $file -NoNewLine
        
}

"$($sum)" | Add-Content -Path $file
```

}

Comment: Have you looked into jobs and `ForEach-Object -Parallel`?

Comment: Ok, this is possible on PS5 using Runspace or `Start-ThreadJob` from the Microsoft ThreadJob module but by looking at your code it's not clear what your expected result is because this will get you a `Result.csv` file that will have only 1 line with all the results concatenated.

Comment: I gotta agree with Santi here. What's the desired result, besides having it done "faster"? What should your output look like?

Comment: The output is a Result.csv file with count of all founded words by .csv file

Comment: Please, edit your question and add a representation of what your expected output would be (preferably in CSV format).

Comment: you can search for ALL the keywords you show by using `-match` against a regex pattern like `Thing1|OtherThing666|ThatThing5`.

Comment: This shouldn't require parallel threads to improve the performance. Just [avoid wrapping cmdlet pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#avoid-wrapping-cmdlet-pipelines) by creating [`PSCustomObject`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) and at the end of the pipeline using `Export-Csv $file` to stream them to the output.

Comment: @zett42 `Foreach-Object -Parallel` is a Powershell 7 feature. The OP explicitly asks for Powershell 5.